# how to set the scroll indicator at the same when app ll be loaded

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application, in that app i want to use scroll for some data but when ever we touch there then the scroll indicator will display but i want to give hint to client there is scroll so you can scroll when the app will start...

when app will be loaded at the same time i want to give the hint to client therer is scroll indicator u can scroll and see the next value so can any one give me the solution...

i know there is horizontal and vertical scroll indicator but it will appear when we touch on that but i want before touch...

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make them visible at all times, but you can use the `UIScrollView`'s `flashScrollIndicators` method to make them appear for a small amount of time.

This should hopefully be enough to show the user that the content is scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Call `[scrollView flashScrollIndicators]` in `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: in iOS 7 this sometimes does not work. I call `[scrollView performSelector: @selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];` instead in `viewDidAppear` of the VC or in `didMoveToWindow` of the custom `UIScrollView` subclass.